# Does SequenceMatcher is supported by chaquopy

Tags: python-3.x, android-studio, difflib, chaquopy, sequencematcher

does chaquopy support

```
from difflib import SequenceMatcher
```

or pip will be install first and what pip will be used to use the SequenceMatcher

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`difflib` is part of the [standard library](https://docs.python.org/3/library/difflib.html), so there's no need to install it with pip.